# How to add event in alamkanak week view

Tags: java, android, android-library, android-calendar

I am using [alam kanak week view](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View) in my app. I have an event for which I know the date, the start time and the end time. Now what function to call to add this event to the weekview. Suppose the date I have is 20-10-2015 and time is 17:30 to 18:30.
I am unable to add this event to the view. Please provide if there is anything.

This is how Alam-Kanak is adding an event:

```
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth-1);
        startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, newYear);
        startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
        endTime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth - 1);
        WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent(3, "Test title", startTime, endTime);
        event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_03));
        CommonItems.events.add(event);
```

This event shows up. 
This is the response I am getting from my server for my custom event:

> {   "error": false,   "appointments": [
>       {
>         "id": "1",
>         "staff_id": null,
>         "technician_id": "1",
>         "name": "Test",
>         "address": "Vijayanagar",
>         "pincode": "580040",
>         "mobile": "9876543210",
>         "email": "test@gmail.com",
>         "date": "2015-09-22",
>         "time": "16:30:00",
>         "latitude": null,
>         "longitude": null,
>         "status": "open",
>         "created_at": "2015-09-06 18:04:47",
>         "updated_at": null
>       }   ] }

This is how I am adding my event:

```
try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("appointments");
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject index = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = index.getString("name"); 

                String date = index.getString("date");
                String[] dateSplit = date.split("-");
                int date_year = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
                int date_month = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
                int date_day = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]);

                String time = index.getString("time");
                String[] timeSplit = time.split(":");
                int time_hour = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[0]);
                int time_minute = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[1]);

                Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
                startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time_minute);
                startTime.set(Calendar.DATE, date_day);
                startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, date_month);
                startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, date_year);
                Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
                endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4+1);
                endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time_minute);

                WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent(1, name, startTime, endTime);
                event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_01));

                CommonItems.events.add(event);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This wont show up.! I am unable to understand whats wrong. Please help.

Comment: this code should add the event, whats the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

I have done this way by little bit change in library:

Change **onSingleTapConfirmed** @Override method:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

        if (mEventClickListener != null) {
             boolean didSelect = false;
             if (mEventRects != null) {
             List<EventRect> reversedEventRects = mEventRects;
             Collections.reverse(reversedEventRects);

              for (EventRect event : reversedEventRects) {
                        if (event.rectF != null && e.getX() > event.rectF.left
                                                && e.getX() < event.rectF.right
                                                && e.getY() > event.rectF.top
                                                && e.getY() < event.rectF.bottom) {
                                            mEventClickListener.onEventClick(
                                                    event.originalEvent, event.rectF);
                                            playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
                                            didSelect = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!didSelect) {
                                    int day_1 = mFirstVisibleDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                                    int day_2 = mLastVisibleDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

                                    int chosen_day;

                                    if (day_1 != day_2) {
                                        chosen_day = (int) (day_1 - 1 + Math.round((e.getX()  - mHeaderColumnPadding - (mNumberOfVisibleDays-1)*mColumnGap - mTextSize)
                                                / mWidthPerDay));
                                    } else {
                                        chosen_day = day_1;
                                    }

                                    Calendar RETCAL = Calendar.getInstance();

                                    RETCAL.setTime(mFirstVisibleDay.getTime());

                                    // int totalY = mScroller

                                    int chosen_hour = Math.max(Math.min((int) Math.round((e.getY() - mHeaderTextHeight - mHeaderRowPadding  - mHeaderMarginBottom - mScroller
                                            .getCurrY()) / mHourHeight),23),0);


                                    RETCAL.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, chosen_day);
                                    RETCAL.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, chosen_hour-1);
                                    RETCAL.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                                    mEventClickListener.onNonEventSingleTap(RETCAL);


                                }

                            }
          return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }
```

**EventClickListener** **interface** will looks like below:

```
public interface EventClickListener {
       public void onEventClick(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect);
       public void onNonEventSingleTap(Calendar cal);
  }
```

Now you will get Calendar object in your **Activity** or **Fragment** class:

```
@Override
    public void onNonEventSingleTap(Calendar cal) {
      // User cal object as Calendar
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry but you did not fully understand my concern, I want to know how to add a new event to the calendar. Like if I know a date and a time, how to set that as a event in my calendar. But this is a very useful information nevertheless. Thank you for this as well.

Comment: @Akshat, As per my understand you want to add new event when you click on the portion of weekview or dayview ? Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: Yes but the part where I am getting trouble is showing up the event in calendar. Please see my question again, I have update it with all the things I am doing to add the event and show it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

hi mate y have this code and it works for me.

there you got two ways to add events.

the thing is that when you add the month variable it needs to be (month-1)
like if you want to add an event on july you must insert 7-1=6;

```
public List<WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
    // Populate the week view with some events.
    List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();

    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 19);
    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
    endTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 19);
    endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    endTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent(0, "Epoca", startTime, endTime);
    event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    events.add(event);


    startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.set(2015, 10, 19, 6, 00);
    endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2015, 10, 19, 9, 00);
    WeekViewEvent event2 = new WeekViewEvent(0,"00kjbhjbhjbjbhj",startTime, endTime);
    event2.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    events.add(event2);


    return events;
}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

may be the issue is your events are added but u have set the event month as **`startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, date_month);`** it is not the previous month. so your events are added on the same date of previous month. check that.. if thats the case then just replace that line with

```
startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, date_month+1);
```